# How to use the specified data generated using a binary tree PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to use the specified data generated using a binary tree PHP?

Here is my **Database**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yy_user_relations (
  id bigint(32) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'User ID',
  cid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parent ID',
  deep int(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Deep',
  area tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Area',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY ucda (uid,cid,deep,area) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=114 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='关系';

INSERT INTO yy_user_relations (id, uid, cid, deep, area) VALUES
    (108, 71, 1, 1, 0),
    (109, 72, 71, 1, 0),
    (110, 72, 1, 2, 0),
    (111, 73, 1, 1, 1),
    (112, 74, 73, 1, 1),
    (113, 74, 1, 2, 1);
area = 0  left, area=1 right
```

[image]

Comment: You may follow the following tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-2/, all you need to first select the data from the table and then using a loop implement the algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to  code, but I failed

Comment: @Aries show your attempt then, and maybe people can help you to improve it. Then a) your requirement will be clearer) and b) you can show that you don't just want us to do the whole work for you.